# Encrypt and decrypt end up corrupt files except text document

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I'm using XOR encryption and I had tried to read and write using the command below.

```
-File.ReadAllBytes / File.WriteAllBytes
-FileStream.Read / FileStream.Write
```

Both corrupts encrypted file except for text document.
Text document perfectly decrypted without any missing / wrong value.

I need suggestion and explanation of why I can't encrypt files other than text document.
Will `BinaryReader` work?

Thank you before.

Edit :

First, I read the file and key into byte array, then I loop and use ApplyVernam to encrypt byte per byte and insert into output variable (byte array too)
And finally I write the file.

```
    private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.txtFileName.Text == string.Empty) { return; }

        try
        {
            this.ReadFile();
            this.ResBytes = new byte[this.FileBytes.Length];

            int x = 0;

            while (x < this.FileBytes.Length)
            {
                this.ResBytes[x] = this.ApplyVernam(this.FileBytes[x], this.FileBytes[x]);
                x++;
            }

            this.WriteFile();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Apply Vernam Function here

```
    public byte ApplyVernam(byte inByte, byte keyByte)
    {
        if (inByte == keyByte) { return inByte; }
        else { return (byte)(inByte ^ keyByte); }
    }
```

This is how I read and write the file (please ignore the write file path)

```
    private void ReadFile()
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(this.txtFilePath.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
        {
            int x = 0;

            this.FileBytes = new byte[(int)br.BaseStream.Length];
            int length = (int)br.BaseStream.Length;

            while (x < length)
            {
                this.FileBytes[x] = br.ReadByte();

                x++;
            }

            br.Close();
        }
    }

    private void WriteFile()
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(this.OutputPath, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            foreach (byte b in this.ResBytes)
            {
                bw.Write(b);
            }

            bw.Flush();
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think problem is where/how you perform encryption (you should post that code).

Comment: I will add my encryption code. I hope nobody complains and ask me to use .NET library cause I'm trying to do it myself. Btw thank you for replying.

Comment: Someone replied that binary readers will work bla bla.. in my notification, but I cant find the full answer, what the hell happened?

Comment: I have a question: why you converto byte to (bit) string, then process a string then back again to byte? Can't you work directly with bits (and to XOR you just need ^) in "original format"?

Comment: That answer was wrong and who post it did delete it, so far you do not have enough rep to see deleted answers.

Comment: Yes you're right that I can simply use ^ but I think it only works for byte array, not byte. I want to do it byte per byte.

Comment: ^ works for integers (then with bytes too). To use it with an array you need to loop through them: for (int i=0; i < array.Length; ++i) array[i] = array[i] ^ key; In your case then a loop over bytes to write (and on read bytes) is what you need. You can even create your own EncryptedStream stream (derived from Stream) to apply encryption to any stream (string, file, memory, network) regardless upper layers (stream for text or binary and/or compressed streams).

Comment: I think its a good idea to apply that to my code as it's better and shorter, but I don't think it will work like what I do, cause I'm pretty sure the problem is not in my encryption, am I wrong?

Comment: IMO yes. Problem is not in WriteFile()/ReadFile(). They works (well even if you keep everything in memory and it may not be efficient) so I'd look in encryption (IMO a conversion to string to...manage bits...has a really _bad smell_).

Comment: Oh about the ^ one, I tried it with both byte in ApplyVernam function, but it returns int rather than byte.

Comment: Yes bit operators work with integers. Just cast to byte: `(byte)(inByte ^ keyByte)`

Comment: I tried (byte)(inByte ^ keyByte), only text document works, word document still corrupts.

Comment: Please show where you call ApplyVernam...

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I change most of my code, please check it above, it's still not working.